# Jenkins Job status is SUCCESS but Ansible playbook fails

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am executing ansible playbook from Jenkins scripted pipeline and I need help in capturing ansible playbook status (success/failed).

```
sh "ansible-playbook -i <args>"
```

> > PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
> >
> > serverName : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
> >
> > [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
> >
> > Finished: SUCCESS

In the above example, I have 1 failure but Jenkins job status is SUCCESS. How can I change the Jenkins job status to FAIL when playbook has at least 1 failure?

Answer (score 1):

> `sh "ansible-playbook -i <args>"`

I would guess the shell block is not set to `set -e` and thus, like most shell scripts, it does not consider a failed command to be a failure of the script as a whole. A grave antipattern, IMHO, but easily the majority of the scripts I've seen

So, I believe `sh "set -e; ansible-playbook -i ..."` will straighten that out, or (in theory) you can use `exec` since that is the only command present, and thus the failure of ansible-playbook *is* the failure of that shell: `sh "exec ansible-playbook -i ..."`